# Is there a way to change the data structure of mesh?

Tags: mesh

I want to convert the mesh data structure to a half-edge mesh and export it as an fbx file.
Are there any resources or methods I can refer to?

Comment: for such a task i would rather suggest to use meshllab than blender

Comment: thank you for the reply